# QGraphicsView/Scene - items are drawn 2x away from mouse click

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I've been trying to use the graphic view framework to draw nodes where I click. However, I can't get the position right.

This behaviour happens : I click on the yellow point and the node appears there
[image: I click on the yellow point and the node appears there.]

So here's the code for mainwindow.cpp :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {

  scene = new GraphScene(this);
  ui->setupUi(this);

  ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
  ui->graphicsView->setSceneRect(ui->graphicsView->rect());
  ui->graphicsView->setFrameStyle(0);
  ui->graphicsView->show();
}
```

the custom scene mousePressEvent:

```
void GraphScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
if (!this->itemAt(event->scenePos(), QTransform())){
    this->addItem(new NodeItem(event->scenePos()));
    this->update();
}
}
```

And the node item :

```
NodeItem::NodeItem(QPointF position) {
    this->setPos(position) ;
}

void NodeItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget){
    painter->drawEllipse(pos(), 30.0, 30.0);
}

QRectF NodeItem::boundingRect() const{
    return QRectF(pos(), QSizeF(30,30));
}
```

I tried my best to fix it but I've stuck for a while and can't fix it. I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene` handle different coordinate systems, in the case of `boundingRect()` and `paint()` methods they must do in local coordinates with respect to the item and you should not use the `pos()` method since that refers to coordinates with respect to the scene.

```
void NodeItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * /*option*/, QWidget * /*widget*/){
    painter->drawEllipse(boundingRect());
}

QRectF NodeItem::boundingRect() const{
    return QRectF(QPointF(-15, -15), QSizeF(30,30));
}
```

Comment: @HajAyedAmir Check my update, it is an improvement of the previous version.